# How can I set a sub-class to a property that is a super-class in obj-c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop, inheritance, properties

Consider the following implementation of a few classes:

**.h file implementations of three different classes**

```
//superClass.h
...
@interface superClass

//Insert useful code

@end

//subClass.h
...
@interface subClass : superClass

//Insert useful code

@end

//Another class that uses various sub-classes of superClass
@interface anotherClass
{
    superClass* myObj;
}
@property (strong, atomic) superClass* myObj;

@end
```

**.m file implementation of `anotherClass`**

```
@implementation anotherClass

@synthesize myObj;

...
//All of the code that uses the myObj property...
...

@end
```

How can I set an instance of `subClass` to an instance of property `anotherClass.myObj`?

In my specific case, I would like to define a property that is a `UIViewController`.  I have multiple sub-classed, UIViewControllers and I need to be able to swap them in and out on a specific property within my iOS app.

Each time I've tried to set one of my child UIViewControllers to my `UIViewController` property, the app crashes.  However, if I re-define the property to be an instance of one of child classes and then instantiate a sub-class, it works perfectly.  I really need to have the ability to swap these controllers in and out.  How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

Well, apologies to all who have been looking at this.  After getting an obvious answer, I decided to re-write all of the associated code.  I created a new property, with a different name, commented out all of my assignment code and re-wrote it to point to the new property.  It's working just as it should.  I'm not sure why this wouldn't work the first time but it is now behaving as it should.  I'm still not clear, however, why my app was crashing.

Comment: Assignment of a subclass to a superclass-typed variable is perfectly legal and can't be causing a problem. It's done _constantly_ in UIKit. Please post more details about the crash and what else you're doing with the objects before and after assignment.

Comment: Thanks Josh (and Caleb) I'll mark Caleb's response as the answer.  I'm not sure what's going on because I had assumed that this would work and since it wouldn't I was getting lost.  I'll fiddle around with the code more, and see if I can formulate a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the assignment. Every instance of `subClass` is also an instance of `superClass`. That's [subtype polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism) in action.

Comment: Correct, however, it's not working in the case that I outlined in the last few paragraphs.

Comment: @RLH Can you at least tell us *why* it's crashing? What error message do you get when it crashes? What happens when you debug the issue? What method causes the crash? It wouldn't hurt to post the (real) code in question, too.

Comment: This is the code: `myProperty = [[SubUIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubUIView" bundle:nil];
`.  When my app hits that line, it kicks out the error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MasterClass setMyProperty:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x399210'`.

Comment: Looks like you need to post some of your real code.  Does MasterClass declare setMyProperty?  If so, did you remember to include MasterClass.h in SubUIViewController.m?

Comment: I expect it must be more like `foo.myProperty = ...`, since `-setMyProperty:` wouldn't be called otherwise. So, why doesn't MasterClass have a setter for myProperty?